# How can I determine whether the device is a phone or tablet using the Unity Engine, and can it be done in C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, platform-independent

Maybe it was asked before, but I did a research and found only solutions for JS but I need a solution for my problem in C#.

So, basically I want to know if my game runs on small phone screens of tablets, independent of platform (iOS, Droid, WP8).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe what he means is "How can I determine whether the device is a phone or tablet using the Unity Engine, and can it be done in C#?"

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I believe the way I wrote it is also understandable to all. Also, not the whole world is english speaking so grammatical, textual perfection is not possible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Screen.height](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html) and [Screen.dpi](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html) to calculate the physical screen height and then set a threshold, where you say it is a phone or a tablet. And maybe another threshold, if you want to differentiate a phablet.

```
float screenHeightInInch =  Screen.height / Screen.dpi;
if (screenHeightInInch < 3.1)
{
    // it's a phone
}
else
{
    // it's tablet
}
```

Comment: mmm I have a movile with 5.5 and not is table pfff so bad solution

Comment: you could adjust the threshold value, if you want bigger phones to be categorized as phones.

Comment: Unfortunately Screen.dpi isn't very reliable. It is even mentioned in the documentation: "May return 0 if unable to determine the current DPI." – I'm just now having trouble in the iOS simulator. I only get 0 for the DPI there. Which may be correct behaviour, given that it's no real physical iPhone. But not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can use [iPhone.generation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iPhone-generation.html) and [iPhoneGeneration](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iPhoneGeneration.html) to detect iPad or not.

For the other platforms, I think you should use [Screen](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html).height,width(Aspect ratio), dpi or such kind of stuff to determine the screen size is Tablet or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadImage : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private UnityEngine.UI.Image image = null;
   public GameObject mainCamera;
   private void Awake()
   {
       int value = GetDeviceId();
       if (image != null)
       {
           if (value==0)
           {
               // it's a Iphone
               image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/BGMM");
           }
           else if (value==1)
           {
               // it's IphoneMax
               image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/BGMM");
           }
           else if (value == 2)
           {
              // it's IPad
               image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/2732");
           }
       }
   }
public int GetDeviceId()
{

    float val = 1.77f;

    float width = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().pixelWidth;

    float height = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().pixelHeight;
    
    if (width > height)
    {
        val = width / height;
    }
    else
    {
        val = height / width;
    }

    if (val > 1.7f && val < 1.8f)
    {
        return 0;

    }
    else if (val > 2.1f && val < 2.2f)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (val > 1.3f && val < 1.4f)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello. Please avoid code only answer. Explain what it does and why you propose this solution.

Comment: @Itération122442 This code load Images from Resource folder and GetDeviceId() function calculate the values whether it is IPhone, IPad or Android.

Comment: @invoguedeveloper Please edit your answer and add your explanation there.